# parse.com - Delete specific notification from status bar on android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push

I want to delete a specific notification from the android status bar with the function: cancel().

for that I need the notification ID.

How can I get this ID from the parse.com notification?

Comment: could you post the code for your custom BroadCastReceiverClass first please?

Comment: I don't use BroadCastReceiverClass.

Comment: In the BroadCastRecieverClass the notification ID is set. AS of now by default parse implements its own class within your app but to control the id, intent and other details of the notification you have to set it up first.

Comment: I don't use BroadCastReceiverClass.  I use: ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.

Comment: sorry, my internet went off. The answer below is incomplete but is enough to give you a head start. Im writing from my mobile phone. Are you facing any particular issues using the below code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this will require some amount of experimentation. Basically you need a BroadCaster Parse's custom class. So you will need to extend that and made a custom class of your own where you can handle custom events such as making the notifications using notification builder

EDIT: REPLACED the entire code. This is working.

```
  public class MyCustomReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        String payload=intent.getExtras().toString();

        Log.d("PARSEPUSH", payload);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        PendingIntent piIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,
                notificationIntent,0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("My Notification").setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.star_on)
                .setContentText("Message Body").setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(piIntent);

        Notification pnNotif = mBuilder.build();

        Integer notificationId=0;

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, pnNotif);  // Set notification ID

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushReceive(context, intent);
    }

    public MyCustomReceiver() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected Notification getNotification(Context context, Intent intent) {
    return null;
    }
}
```

Make sure you update the manifest and replace ParsePushBroadcastReveiver with MyCustomReceiver.

Comment: ya sorry, one line didnt get copied. I forgot to mention which icon to use for the notification. It is coming now.. use intent.getExtras.toString() to read the payload being sent in the push notification. Treat this as a json and retrieve the message payload from it.

Comment: i tried this code but when i do that i don't get the notifications at the satus bar. where do i set the id? for example i need somthing like this:-  notificationManager.notify(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

Comment: The notification comes at the status bar. This is working fine for me. Check two things. One make sure you are seeing a Log.d output. This will at least show that this broadcaster is being called. Secondly make sure your manifest is declared and updated properly. See the last line  mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, pnNotif); . notificationId IS your custom ID. just replace that with MY_NOTIFICAION_ID . Just remember that this can only be an integer value.